# UDP - Java Server sends String to C++/CLI .net Client

Tags: java, sockets, c++-cli, client, server

I'm trying to send a stream of Strings from a Java server to a C++/CLI Client, but before doing that I wanted to start with the simplest case, i.e. send a single String from a Java Server to a C++/CLI client and display it.
The examples I found in the literature or in tutorials didn't work for me, knowing that the same Java Server communicated easily with another Java Client (either on the same machine or on different machines).
Without further ado, here's my Code:

> the Java Server Side: SendStringToCpp.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SendStringToCpp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String message = "message"; // The String that contains the information
        byte[] sentBytes = message.getBytes();

        System.out.println("Message: " + message);

        ServerSocket s = null;
        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(30011);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Socket s1 = null;
        try {
            s1 = s.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  


        OutputStream s1out = null;
        try {
            s1out = s1.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (s1out);

        try {
            //dos.writeUTF(message); // Sending the String  
              dos.write(sentBytes);  // Sending the bytes  


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            s1out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            s1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    } 
}
```

> The C++ Client Side: ReceiveStringFromJava.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <exception>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::IO;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Creating the Socket..."); 
    try {
        //Socket^ listener = gcnew Socket(AddressFamily::InterNetwork, SocketType::Dgram, ProtocolType::Udp);
        //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
        UdpClient^ receivingUdpClient = gcnew UdpClient();
        IPEndPoint^ RemoteIpEndPoint = gcnew IPEndPoint(IPAddress::Any, 30011);
        //listener->Bind(RemoteIpEndPoint);
        array <Byte>^ receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient->Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint); // get the Bytes array from the end poitn
        String^ receivedString = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(receiveBytes); // retrieve the string from the received Bytes
        Console::WriteLine("This is the message received {0}", receivedString);
        //  Console::WriteLine("this message was send from {0} on their ort number {1}", RemoteIpEndPoint->Address, RemoteIpEndPoint->Port);     

    }
    catch (Exception^ e) {
        Console::WriteLine("Error!  ");
        Console::WriteLine( e->ToString());
    } 
    Console::ReadLine(); 
    return 0;
}
```

> And Here's the Exception printed on the Console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTDqm.jpg

P.S. I tried to Bind the IPEndPoint to the Socket (it's commented above), but to no avail, and gave the same Error.

```
Socket^ listener = gcnew Socket(AddressFamily::InterNetwork, SocketType::Dgram, ProtocolType::Udp);
.
.
 listener->Bind(RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`UdpClient constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35e07es2.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) that allows binding to a listening port.

Quoting MSDN (emphasis mine):

> Initializes a new instance of the UdpClient class **and binds it to the
>   local port number provided**.

```
UdpClient^ receivingUdpClient = gcnew UdpClient(30011);
//                  specify the port both here  ^^^^^  and here vvvvv
IPEndPoint^ RemoteIpEndPoint = gcnew IPEndPoint(IPAddress::Any, 30011);
array <Byte>^ receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient->Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Comment: The Error is gone. But, I can't get anything on the C++/CLI side. 

Here are the screenshots:

JavaSide
http://i.imgur.com/YlMOCrB.png

C++/CLI Side
http://i.imgur.com/hAobySP.png

Comment: `ServerSocket` is for TCP communication. You want `DatagramSocket` for UDP communication.

Comment: Now it works!
 So, if I get this:
- To receive UDP data on the C++/Cli client, I should use Java datagramSockets 
- and if I want to received from a java ServerSocket, I should use TCP on the C++/Cli side?

Here are the screen Shots --
JavaSide: http://i.imgur.com/32y7xKE.png
C++/CLI Side: http://i.imgur.com/a9y7Qcv.png